# Проблемы с парсингом wildberries

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Пишу парсер wildberries. При парсинге Header и Footer проблем не возникает, но когда перехожу к парсингу карточек товаров то возвращается пустой массив. Парсятся только самые верхние уровни (например div с id="app"), никак не получается добраться до карточек товаров. Может подскажете что я делаю не так?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

HOST = 'https://wildberries.ru/'
URL = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?sort=popular&search=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8&targetUrl=XS#c35678773'
HEADERS = {
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "app"})
    cards = []
    print(items)


html = get_html(URL)
get_content(html.text)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wildberries

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'https://search.wb.ru/exactmatch/ru/common/v4/search?' \
      '&curr=rub' \
      '&lang=ru' \
      '&locale=ru' \
      '&query=водолазки' \
      '&resultset=catalog' \
      '&sort=popular' \
      '&page=1'
resp = requests.get(url)
prod = resp.json()['data']['products']
dd = []
for model in prod:
    print('Бренд:', model['brand'])
    print('Цена:', model['salePriceU'] / 100, "руб.")
```